# Decoding message using dictionary on string in Python

Tags: python

When I'm using a dictionary to replace values in a string for decoding of a message, how do I put it in such that the function doesn't read a replaced value as a key and replace a replaced value again?

```
def decipher_message(translation_guide, message):
    t = read_translation_guide_into_dictionary(translation_guide)
    e = read_message(message)

    print(t)

    print(e)

    for key, value in t.items():
            f = e
            e = f.replace(key, value)

    return e
```

Output:

> {'a': 'm', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'd': 'y', 'e': 't', 'f': 'v', 'g': 'o',
>   'h': 'u', 'i': 'x', 'j': 'e', 'k': 'j', 'l': 'w', 'm': 'f', 'n': 'z',
>   'o': 'd', 'p': 'l', 'q': 'i', 'r': 'k', 's': 'h', 't': 'n', 'u': 'g',
>   'v': 'b', 'w': 'q', 'x': 's', 'y': 'p', 'z': 'r'}
>
> "qa mqtbppd vjqtu mghto! esbtr dgh mgz mqtoqtu aj gs rqto xezbtujz. q
>   ahxe ejpp dgh, qex whqej vgzqtu sbfqtu bpp esj ljbpes qt esj lgzpo. qm
>   dghzj pggrqtu mgz qe, q vhzqjo b aby eg qe bzghto lsjzj dghzj xebtoqtu
>   tgl! zjajavjz esghus: ljbpes qxte jfjzdesqtu qt esj lgzpo!"
>
> '"if finallp being fdgnd! nhank pdg fdr finding fe dh kind snranger. i
>   fgsn nell pdg, ins qgine bdring habing all nhe qealnh in nhe qdrld. if
>   pdgre lddking fdr in, i bgried a fap nd in ardgnd qhere pdgre snanding
>   ndq! refefber nhdggh: qealnh isnn eberpnhing in nhe qdrld!"'

Comment: what `f = e` & `e = f.replace(key, value)` supposed to do? why not just `e = e.replace(key, value)`?

Comment: Please do not make substantial changes to your question after it has received one or more relevant answers! If you have another question, please ask it in a fresh question.

Comment: @Cloud11 we typically frown upon changing a question substantially after others have answered it.  It renders their efforts moot as the question being asked is no longer the one that they answered.  No answerer likes this and it doesn't help to improve the quality of the content on the site.  PM2Ring gave good advice.  If you have another, different question, please ask it.  We like having more questions to answer.  We just don't like having the ones we've answered changed.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. When you post a question or answer on a Stack Exchange site you agree that any and all content is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms. Please see [legal/terms-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) for details. Your question isn't just for your benefit. It's also supposed to help future readers as well.

Comment: Stop defacing your question. You have got answers. If you have a new question please ask a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.join` with the following generator expression that iterates over the string to translate each character:

```
def decipher(translation, message):
    t = read_translation(translation)
    e = read_message(message)
    return ''.join(t.get(c, c) for c in e)
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than iterating through the dictionary and running a replace against the whole string, you should iterate through the string and replace each character with its value in the dict:

```
decoded = []
for letter in e:
    decoded.append(t.get(letter, letter))
return ''.join(decoded)
```

Note also that Python has a built-in string translate method, which takes a table which can be generated from your dict:

```
table = str.maketrans(t)
return e.translate(table)
```